# I can't execute .pyw file by double-click

Tags: python

I can't run my test.pyw file by double-click ,here's my code:

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

toast = ToastNotifier()
toast.show_toast('test title','test content')
```

I'm sure my python env is work,cause I can run the code by command line `python test.py` , but after I changed Extension name to `test.pyw` it can't run by double-click.
And also I can run another `demo.pyw`, double-click it created `1.txt`,here's the `demo.pyw` code:

```
import time
fout = open('e:\\1.txt','w')
tmp = '%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d \r\n' % time.localtime()[0:6]
print(tmp)
fout.write(tmp)
fout.flush()
```

Is this because I used third-party package `win10toast`?

Comment: If you rename the file to have a `.py` extension and run it from a command line, what happens? Do you get an exception? How have you installed Python on your system? Do you have the `py.exe` launcher in your path?

Comment: It's probably because you didn't have the Python installer associate the `.pyw` extension with Python. The extension only matters for Windows determining the default handler; it doesn't magically change how imports are handled.

Comment: Calling `print()` in a `.pyw` will fail (silently) because there's no `stdout` and `stderr`. The same script might work if its extension was changed to `.py` because those output streams _will_ exist in that case.